# MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 34.93.94.239:27017 closed - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, client

I am using MongoClient in nodejs to insert bulk records into a database. I am using `async.eachOfLimit` to do this in batches.

```
let cursor2 = await consultation_collection
      .find({ processed: { $exists: false } })
      .limit(limit)
      .toArray();

await eachOfLimit(cursor2, 2, insertData);
```

However, after inserting about 50-60 records , I am constantly getting this error-

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 34.93.94.239:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Santosh Chirag\Downloads\migrate-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: 'atlas-bagddj-shard-0',
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(3) {
      'medv5-dev-shard-00-00.to7mj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'medv5-dev-shard-00-01.to7mj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'medv5-dev-shard-00-02.to7mj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: 9
  }
}
```

The code runs fine if I press `enter` , then it inserts 10-15 records more and this error occurs again continuously.
What is this error regarding and how to make `Mongo` stay connected till all the records have been inserted